# LAPS Update-AdmPwdADSchema doesn't add the attributes

Tags: windows, active-directory, password-management

So I've installed LAPS according to [THIS](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/step-by-step-guide-how-to-configure-microsoft-local/ba-p/2806185) article. I've done this on 3 domains so far with *great success* but on the 4th one, for some reason, the attributes ms-Mcs-AdmPwd and ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime doesn't show up.

I've confirmed that the LAPS user is created on the servers and the software is installed but still nothing.

When I run Update-AdmPwdADSchema it says "EntryAlreadyExists" but it does not.
[image: EntryAlreadyExists]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas? I'm starting to lose it...

EDIT, solution:

[image]

Comment: If you check in Schema Management MMC the attribute probably does exist. You need to check that in the MMC, and also the Computer class, to see if it has been modified to use the new attributes.

Comment: Hi @GregAskew thank you, for some reason the atributes was not added to computer objects in the schema, it works now! If you want to write it as a "official reply" I can mark it as the solution. Again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check in Schema Management MMC the attribute probably does exist. You need to check that in the MMC, and also the Computer class, to see if it has been modified to use the new attributes.