# LAPS Update-AdmPwdADSchema not listed in AD attributes

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2022, password-management

Having issue getting AD to see added attributes.

(found this - [LAPS Update-AdmPwdADSchema doesn't add the attributes](https://serverfault.com/questions/1117494/laps-update-admpwdadschema-doesnt-add-the-attributes) - does not say how added.

Have ran the scripts to add the attributes. Says they already exist. Check AD computer attributes and they are not listed. Found the above mention but not seeing what they did or how. Am still currently googling to see if able to figure out.

[schema layout - listed but not able to change to yes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCipl.png)
Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: `Check AD computer attributes`. First thing to check is schmgmt.msc and look at it and see if the expected attributes are present.